# Keep query in search bar, but use placeholder for initial default value

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have a search bar that returns matching data according to what I type. To make it user-friendly I made the input value keep the search query in the bar even after pressing submit. However, when I initially load my page without having done any searches, "null" appears instead of my placeholder. How do I make my placeholder the default value when first running the page? I also have a NullPointerException when I run my project and am wondering if that may be related.

[image: Says null upon initial start, doesn't use placeholder]

Here is the search bar code:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="index.jsp">

        Search <input type="text" name="searchRequest"
            placeholder="Enter your search here..."
            value="<%=request.getParameter("search")%>" /> <input type="submit"
            id="button1" value="Search" name="submit" />


    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is you can check for null first. To do that download `jstl-1.2.jar` file, put it in `WEB-INF/lib` and modified your jsp with following code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> // add at start of jsp page


<form method="post" id="form1" action="index.jsp">
    Search <input type="text" name="searchRequest" placeholder="Enter your search here..." <c:if test="${request.getParameter != null}">value="<%=request.getParameter("search")%>"</c:if> /> 
    <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Search" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious to me that `value="<%=request.getParameter("search")%>"` is what is giving you the null pointer exception and causing it to be null initially. Since their is no get parameter initially(its unset) the value is null. Value should be "" or not have a value initially initially and change after a user enters something. You can use php to do this, javascript, or probably some other language. If request.getParameter() allows you to use a default parameter you should set it to a "", or you should have the search url have an empty string parameter initially. Their are many ways to get your modeled behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then writing long code just put `${search}` replacing `<%=request.getParameter("search")%>`

You will no longer receive null. This EL(Expression language). NO extra library will be required for this to be added and it will work just fine.
This I can tell you by my personal experience.